# some setting in VS Code

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I'm writing tensorflow in vscode, but there seems no highlighting.
[image]

is there any plugin to highlight the code?

I'm sure that i have installed 'python','magicpython','tensorflow',just as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the extension "[Visual Studio Code Tools for AI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.vscode-ai)" improves the syntax highlighting.

I do see some in this picture:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai/master/docs/media/deeplearning-ide.png]

See more at "[Train a TensorFlow model locally](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai/blob/master/docs/tensorflow-local.md)"